# WPF MVVM panel toggling with chart control taking too long

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF interface that has a panel used for displaying details about the particular option you have selected from a button bar. Eg if you click the Info button, the detail pane populates with a InfoDetailUserControl. If you click the Graph button, it populates with a GraphDetailUserControl.

The way I am doing this is to define each detail panel as a UserControl. I then have a ViewModel for each UserControl that drives the data. The detail panel is represented by a ContentControl and to display the relevant panel, I set the content of this to the ViewModel representing the UserControl I want to display. I then have a number of DataTemplates that map a ViewModel to a UserControl, so that when you add the VM to the ContentControl, it looks up the datatemplate for that type and displays the relevant UserControl.

Example datatemplates.

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type RunResults:SimpleCalcInfoResultViewModel}">
        <Views:SimpleCalcInfoResult />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type RunResults:TradeResultViewModel}">
        <Views:TradeResult />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type RunResults:GraphResultViewModel}">
        <Views:GraphResult />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type RunResults:NoResultViewModel}">
        <Views:NoResult />
    </DataTemplate>
```

This all works fine, but the problem is that every time you change the content of the detail panel, you supply it the ViewModel class and it then on-the-fly looks up the datatemplate that matches the VM type and creates an instance of that UserControl. It then discards that UserControl when you switch to a different type. Hence if you keep switching between Info and Graph view for example, it keeps recreating the GraphUserControl every time you go back to it, it doesn't cache it from the first load and just redisplay the same view again.

The problem I have is that the Graph UserControl takes 3-4 seconds to initialise, in the InitializeComponent() call. I'm assuming this is just the WPF toolkit chart control being slow but it means the user must wait 4 seconds every time they go back to the Graph view, which is not ideal.

Is there a way I can either easily cache the first UserControl created so it only ever goes through that initialisation once or is there a way I can simply speed up the loading of the Chart control?

Many thanks